# How to fast re-index value in column in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

I am new with SQL Sever. Now I have value in one column that need to substring then re-locate those value.

```
Ex1: "000000000000000000000000000000" 
  => "000000000000000000000000000000"
Ex2: "168000000000000000000000000000"
  => "168000000000000000000000000000"
Ex3: "192000164000000000000000000000"
  => "192164000000000000000000000000"
```

Example `#1` and `#2` is ok because we don't do anything, but example `#3` is very hard.

Please help to write code to **sub-string** and **re-locate** value as output example `#3`?

Thank.

Comment: So, what are you trying to do here exactly, move all non zero characters to the left of the string in order? Are yuo looking for a solution using T-SQL (SQL Server) or Python? Are your strings fixed width, or do they vary?

Comment: Yes, I want to move non zero characters to the left of the string in order by using T-SQL.

Comment: And which language, you didn't answer that. SQL (T-SQL for SQL Server) and Python and totally different languages. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Current, I work with SQL Server 2016. I tried use this code but it show error: "Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 31
'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name". Could you help in SQL Server 2016?

Answer (score 0):

As I do't know your SQL Server version, and you haven't said what language you want this in, here is a SQL Server 2017 answer:

```
--Your Sample Data
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT V.SomeString
    FROM (VALUES('000000000000000000000000000000'),
                ('168000000000000000000000000000'),
                ('192000164000000000000000000000')) V(SomeString)),
--The Solution
N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP 30 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) I
    FROM N N1, N N2),
NonZero AS(
    SELECT V.SomeString,
           T.I,
           SS.C
    FROM VTE V
        CROSS JOIN Tally T
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(V.SomeString,T.I,1))) SS(C)
    WHERE SS.C != '0')
SELECT V.SomeString,
       LEFT(CONCAT(STRING_AGG(NZ.C,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NZ.I),REPLICATE('0',30)),30) AS NewString
FROM VTE V
     LEFT JOIN NonZero NZ ON V.SomeString = NZ.SomeString
GROUP BY V.SomeString;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ef1894811b69f6b38a3f7ca5bc3e9f32)

Comment: Thank for your answer. But it not work in SQL Server 2016

Comment: @ASEANStreetFood, no, it won't, this is a SQL Server 2017 answer; as I didn't know your version nor the lagnuage you wanted you use. You'll need to replace `STRING_AGG` with a `FOR XML PATH` solution.